Snort 2.9.16 Session config flush_on_alert too many parameters error
I saw on the snort manual an setting for the Session global processor called flush_on_alert that I'm interested in. However, when I tried to edit snort.conf to add the setting, I recieved an error upon running snort.
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf(283) => Too many parameters for option in Session config.

I'm confused, as I'm using Snort 2.9.16, and the manual is also written for 2.9.16 any error was unexpected.
Relevant portion of snort.conf:

Snort manual:

http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node17.html#SECTION00322000000000000000
Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask. SOF's networks tag, which seemed relevant, referred me to here.

Don't put comments in the middle of a concat'd record.

The rest-of-line-is-comment # doesn't mix with the concatenate-lines \ operator. Likely, concatenation happens first, leaving the line with a trailing , which supposedly triggers the error you see.
Move # comment elements to the end of the concat section and make sure there's no trailing comma.
